# Dada una fecha (dd-mm-aaaa), obtener el lunes de esa semana. En numero

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy intentando crear una función con información de datapikcer pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.
Dada una fecha, por ejemplo: (01-09-2017), saber cual es el lunes de esta semana¿?
En este caso me tendría que devolver (28-08-2017). (Que sería una caso especial por que el lunes de esta semana corresponde al mes anterior).
Pero un caso normal sería por ejemplo si le paso a la función (06-09-2017), me tendría que devolver (04-09-2017) que es del mismo mes y es el lunes correspondiente a esa semana y a esa fecha.

Comment: Por ejemplo sé y entiendo todo lo que explica en la pregunta que mencionas como posible duplicada.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, seguiré investigando. Es muy diferente lo que plantea esa pregunta.

Comment: podrias decir cual es el resultado para (2017-09-03), opción **A)** 2017-08-28 ó opción **B)** 2017-09-04, ya que dependiendo a calendarios los resultados son diferentes, una vez lo aclares se responderá la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shassain. Es verdad, eso no lo aclaré en la pregunta y es ambiguo. En ese caso sería la opción (A)  2017-08-28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues tomando en cuenta que el día **domingo** es el primer día de la semana, podrías hacer un poco de matemáticas para que te pueda salir el resultado que desees. Te dejo algo de codigo para que puedas revisarlo.

```js
fecha1 = new Date("2017-09-01");
dias1=(fecha1.getUTCDay()-1)*(-1);
fecha1.setDate(fecha1.getDate() + dias1);
console.log("Lunes de la semana:");
console.log(fecha1);
```

Y si en caso tomas en cuenta el **lunes** como el primer día de la semana, entonces :

```js
fecha1 = new Date("2017-09-03");
diapararestar=fecha1.getUTCDay();
if(diapararestar==0){
    dias1=(-6);        
}else{
    dias1=(diapararestar-1)*(-1);        
}

fecha1.setDate(fecha1.getDate() + dias1);
console.log("Lunes de la semana:");
console.log(fecha1);
```

Bueno espero que el código te sirva.

Comment: Fantástico Shassain, era justo lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.